# Webkit/Safari/Firefox/API: Can I programmatically read/extract multiple tabs' URLs?

Tags: javascript, firefox, safari, applescript, automator

Topic: Programmatically manipulate web browser in OS X 10.4.x+ Tiger/Leopard.
Subjects: Webkit, Safari, Firefox, APIs, Applescript, Automator, Javascript, Ruby, Ruby on Rails, OS X, Tiger
Goal: Collect/Read/Extract URLs from Safari into text (Ruby on Rails code) file.
Note: A solution that uses FF would be very appreciated, too. I use Safari (v. 3.x, OS X 10.4.x) more and much prefer a solution that works in Safari.

At times, I use the web browser to find/display multiple site pages that I 1) want to visit again later and 2) the URLs of which I want to group together in a text file for a) future reference and/or b) programmatically manipulate.

For example: In today's NYT I find seven NYT articles I want to post to my del.icio.us acct. and share via email in their "printer friendly" format long after they are headlined in that day's online edition. I open each one in a browser window's tap, then Presto! their URLs automagically are wooshed into a file where a (custom) Ruby on Rails app sends the print versions' URLs to email addresses and my Del.icio.us acct.

I figure there's a way to do the URL extracting step from the OS using Applescript or Automator. I figure there MAY be a way to do it with Javascript.

My Question: How to read the web browser's tabs' location field and collate these strings into a text file (either within my OS or over the wire to a web app.)?

Much appreciated.

Comment: if/when you figure this out - you definitely need to share it back to the world.. I'd love something like this!

Answer (score 2):

For Safari, this would be pretty trivial to do with Applescript.  I'd suggest starting with something like [Bookmark all tabs](http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20060227192533174) to get the basic tab-grabbing logic that you'll need, and maybe merge it into John Gruber's old [Save and restore Safari URLs](http://daringfireball.net/2003/02/save_and_restore_safari_urls) script to save the URLs as a list to a text file.

There may be better Applescript solutions out there, too; those were just the first I found via Google, and both are pretty badly dated.

For further help and resources pertaining to Applescript, I suggest the [MacScripter forums](http://bbs.macscripter.net/).

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

If you desire to do this is Firefox you're going to have to learn and use XUL.  The tabs are not visible to javascript (security/privacy concerns) and there's no API for this sort of information outside of firefox.

[Getting Started with XUL development](http://willcode4beer.com/design.jsp?set=gettingStartedWithXUL) is a good resource for how to start programming in XUL.

IBM has a [decent tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/edu/x-dw-x-xulintro.html) for your first XUL code.

Here is a [tab handler in XUL](http://piro.sakura.ne.jp/xul/_multipletab.html.en) to give you an idea of how to deal with tabs.

A [short tutorial that demonstrates](http://www.sitepoint.com/print/xul-nets-biggest-secret-1/) mixing XUL, javascript, and other technologies to update a website.

Lastly, here's a good [lifehacker tutorial on firefox extensions/add-ons](http://lifehacker.com/software/programming/how-to-build-a-firefox-extension-264490.php) which shows you much of the above for a simple example, and then how to package it as an .xpi so others can easily add it to and manage it from their firefox.

I don't have any insight into Safari, but it's based on webkit and there should be some resources on customizing it similar to how you'd use XUL on firefox.

Good luck!

-Adam

Answer (score 0):

The most simple solution in Firefox is "Bookmark all open tabs" (in the bookmark menu). Give this "bookmark folder" a specific name. You can then go into your profile (http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Profiles) and open the file "bookmarks.html" which contains all the info you want and then some.

If you want to use a UI, check out the Taboo and the "Sitzungs-Manager" (probably Session-Manager). Both are for Firefox 3.0+

Taboo allows you to save a tab for "later reading" (kind of like the bookmark menu but just a single click; will save a screenshot of the page, too).

The session manager plugin allows you to save the currently open tabs and windows and restore them later.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify this bit-0-code to get you started. I used this to build my own personal bookmarking plugin for one tab. You can pop-up a list of urls in a xul window and then select the ones you want to post / arrogate to one place.

```
function getGetDocData(){
var wm = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/appshell/window-mediator;1"]
               .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIWindowMediator);
var mainWindow = wm.getMostRecentWindow("navigator:browser");
var tab  = mainWindow.getBrowser().selectedTab;
titleDG = tab.label;
for(var i = 0; i < window.opener.length; i++){
    var doc = window.opener[i].document;
    if(doc.title == tab.label){
        hrefToDG = doc.location.href;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Here is a script for AppleScript that should get you going (this script is for Safari)...

```
property these_URLs : {}
set the text item delimeters of AppleScript to ""
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--Initialize the program
set the action to the button returned of (display dialog "Create or view a list of favorites..." buttons{"Cancel","View","Create"} default button 3)
if the action is "Create" then
    create_text_file()
else
    open_favorites()
end if

---------------------------------SUBROUTINES--------------------------------------

on create_text_file()
    --get the URL of every tab of every window
    tell application "Safari"
        set theWindows to (get every document) as list
        repeat with i from 1 to the count of theWindows
            set this_Window to item i of theWindows
            set theTabs to (get every tab of this_Window) as list
            repeat with x from 1 to the count of theTabs
                set this_Tab to item x of theTabs
                set this_URL to (the URL of this_tab) as string
                set the end of these_URLs to this_URL
            end repeat
        end repeat
    end tell

    --put the URLs into a text document
    set newFile to (choose file name with prompt "Choose a name and location for the new file:" default location (path to desktop folder))
    try
        open for access newFile with write permission
        set the text item delimiters of AppleScript to return
        set the_URLs to these_URLs as string
        write the_URLS to file newFile
        close access newFile
    on error
        try
            close access newFile
        end try
    end try
    set the text item delimiters of AppleScript to ""
end create_text_file()

on open_favorites()
   --Verify whether you have saved any favorites with this script
   if these_URLs is {} then display dialog "You have not added any favorites with this script." with icon note buttons{"Cancel"}
   --there are favorites so open all the URLs you stored in the text file
   repeat with i from 1 to the count of these_URLs
       set this_URL to item i of these_URLs
       tell application "Safari" to make new tab at the end of tabs of document 1 with properties {URL:this_URL}
   end repeat
end open_favorites
```

If you have any questions, just ask. :)