# Chrome/Firefox: Disable keyboard shortcuts on websites

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox

I am using Outlook Web Access in Chrome and Firefox. On OS X, the webpage uses the keyboard shortcut Option+S for sending off the email. Unfortunately, on OS X the same shortcut is usually used to type the German Umlaut "ß". Hence, whenever I now try to type a word with that character, the website instead sends off my email. Do you know of any plugin or other means to disable such shortcuts on certain websites? Thanks!

Comment: I'd start at http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?t=72994

Answer (score 3):

You can tell Firefox to disable all keyboard shortcuts for websites (as well a couple other options).  Look at this pref on the **about:config** page.

`permissions.default.shortcuts (default = 0)`

The values can be set as follows:

```
UNKNOWN: Services.perms.UNKNOWN_ACTION [0]
ALLOW: Services.perms.ALLOW_ACTION [1]
BLOCK: Services.perms.DENY_ACTION [2]
PROMPT: Services.perms.PROMPT_ACTION [3]
```

Note that there may be some undesirable side effects, e.g. my `fn+delete` macOS System function no longer works to delete the *next* character after my cursor... maybe there's a workaround for that?

I found this solution here:

- https://support.mozilla.org/gl/questions/1241294

---

More context:

I had a similar problem with Outlook Web App (OWA) in Firefox on Macbook (OSX), where I want to refresh the page with `cmd+r` but instead OWA would interpret the shortcut as "reply" and pop-up a new window to reply to the selected message instead of simply refreshing the page.

Comment: I understand that this disables keyboard shortcuts for all websites in Firefox globally. I am also having problems with the keyboard shortcuts of Outlook Web App (OWA), and would like to disable only the shortcuts of this particular page. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Use an OS level tool, such as Automator, to toggle the keybindings based on the browser URL:

- [A guide to using OS X’s Automator to create your own software](http://www.itproportal.com/2013/07/19/a-guide-to-using-os-xs-automator-to-create-your-own-software/)
- [Webkit/Safari/Firefox/API: Can I programmatically read/extract multiple tabs' URLs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299200/)
- [Is there a way to trigger a Hot Key/Keyboard Shortcut via a Shell Script, a AppleScript or a Automator Workflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7810703/)
- [MacOS, how to delete unused service item in Keyboard Shortcuts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17257715/)