# MacOS, how to delete unused service item in Keyboard Shortcuts

Tags: macos, shortcut, automator

I'm a newbie to Mac OS and learning with Automator, I found it useful but not quite controllable. I made a shortcut in services but I don't know how to delete it.

[image]

The item highlighted is what I want to delete. I think I should do it with Automator but I don't find out how.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<kbd>crtl</kbd> + mouse click on the service to get a context menu for the service.

Select Show in Finder.

[image]

This will take you to the service file by opening a new finder window and selecting it.

[image]

You then just need to remove the file from the **Services** folder.

When close and re-open the System Prefs. The Service will not be there anymore.

Comment: Show in Finder doesn't always work. Also you can use the Services Manager which is easier to use.

Comment: @sorin What Services Manager?

Comment: [The Services Manager](http://www.macosxautomation.com/services/servicesmanager/)

Comment: Does Services Manager still work nowadays?

Answer (score 3):

**Here Are Some Good Things to Know Too**

@markhunte seems to have a good answer, but here's another way:

If you are within Automator.app,

- Open the Service that you want to delete.  You may have to choose "Open..." from the menu and type the key-combination command-shift-period to view invisible files such as ~/Library (which is now invisible by default in Mountain Lion.)
- Your services (the ones that are local to your account) are in the folder: ~/Library/Services
- After opening your Service in Automator, hold down the command-key and click the title of the window. (This works in most Mac applications -- not just in Automator to reveal documents in the Finder.)

Once you've found the document in the Finder, you can simply move it to the Trash like any other document.

Also, other kinds of Automator workflows can be found in a similar manner in the following directory:

~/Library/Workflows/Applications

I think that with this sort of Thing that Apple has just made it hard.

- With the folder ~/Library now being hidden by default.
- With having to know the "secret-handshake" command-shift-period to be able to open hidden files.

and

- To have a way to reveal documents in the Finder, but have it also a "secret-handshake" of holding down the command-key while clicking on a document window's title to be able to reveal documents in the Finder.

I think that to get Apple to change these things, the way that they listen is if many developers file a bug report:

Apple's Bug Reporter:
https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/

Answer (score 0):

> Look in ~/Library/Services or /Library/Services

In the Finder, ~/Library is now an invisible folder by default in Mountain Lion.  Of course, people can google for "Mac show hidden files" and find a command to enter into the command-line to make all files and folders visible.  As a programmer, I like being able to see everything.

Unix Command:
defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE

Reference:
http://osxdaily.com/2009/02/25/show-hidden-files-in-os-x/