# MacOS, how to delete uesless service item in Keyboard Shortcuts when cannot find in finder

Tags: macos, service, automation, shortcut

I meet with the same problem with [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17257715/macos-how-to-delete-unused-service-item-in-keyboard-shortcuts/17263771#17263771), but the problem is I find nothing when I click `Show in Finder`. How to deal with this kind of useless service in Mac?

[image]

Then I click `Show in Finder`, the finder window is like this:

[image]

I cannot find any service file related to iTerm2.

Comment: Where did you look for the service file?

Comment: In home path, where `Show in Finder` tell me this path.